# what is the difference between used & hard quota for memory in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes

What is the difference between used and hard quota for memory in kubernetes? How to write correct values in quota of limits.memory & requests.memory? i dont understand it & i didn't find any explanation of this

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#requests-and-limits

Comment: i ve read it, but there is no definition of hard & used quota, hard to understand.

Comment: What is "hard" and "user" quota? Where did you get those terms from?

Comment: in this article https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/ there is mention about resource Used & Hard. what is it?

Comment: `kubectl explain resourcequota`

Comment: In short, `Used` and `Hard` Quota is something similar to resource limits: `requests` and `limits` for pod, but `Quota` is for `Namespace`. I will explain it further with example in a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Background

[Resource Quota](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/) is limit of specific resource which is namespace wide.

> A resource quota, defined by a ResourceQuota object, provides constraints that limit aggregate resource consumption per namespace.

As I mention in comments it's very similar to `Requests` and `Limits` which are used in `Pods`. `Request` is value which is requested by pod on the beginning and `limit` is maximum value which pod can use.
In `Quota`, `hard` value is like `limit`, it cannot have more than this value. `Used` is value of current use of this particular resource. Quota can be used to limit number of `jobs`, `pods`, `services`, `cpu` or `memory`.

### Tests

To list all your `quotas`, you can use command `$ kubectl get quota -A`. If you miss `-A` or `--all-namespaces` you will get only quota from `default` namespace.

I've tested this on `GKE` cluster and `Minikube`.

As default, `GKE` cluster have a few `Quotas`. You can have more than 1 `Quota` in `namespace`. In below example you have 2 `quotas` for `kube-system` namespace.

```
$ kubectl get quota -A
NAMESPACE         NAME                  AGE   REQUEST                      LIMIT
default           gke-resource-quotas   11m   count/ingresses.extensions: 0/100, count/ingresses.networking.k8s.io: 0/100, count/jobs.batch: 0/5k, pods: 0/1500, services: 1/500
kube-node-lease   gke-resource-quotas   11m   count/ingresses.extensions: 0/100, count/ingresses.networking.k8s.io: 0/100, count/jobs.batch: 0/5k, pods: 0/1500, services: 0/500
kube-public       gke-resource-quotas   11m   count/ingresses.extensions: 0/100, count/ingresses.networking.k8s.io: 0/100, count/jobs.batch: 0/5k, pods: 0/1500, services: 0/500
kube-system       gcp-critical-pods     18m   pods: 13/1G 
kube-system       gke-resource-quotas   11m   count/ingresses.extensions: 0/100, count/ingresses.networking.k8s.io: 0/100, count/jobs.batch: 0/5k, pods: 15/1500, services: 3/500
```

But `Minikube` don't have any at the beginning. To enable `Resource Quota`, please check [this docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/#enabling-resource-quota)

You can describe `Quota` to check which resources are going to be limited.

```
$ kubectl describe quota gke-resource-quotas -n kube-system
Name:                              gke-resource-quotas
Namespace:                         kube-system
Resource                           Used  Hard
--------                           ----  ----
count/ingresses.extensions         0     100
count/ingresses.networking.k8s.io  0     100
count/jobs.batch                   0     5k
pods                               15    1500
services                           3     500
```

Based on the above output:

In my current `GKE` cluster I have 15 pods running (`Used`) but maximum number of pods I can have in this namespace is `1500`. I won't be able to deploy in this `namespace` 1501 pods.

**Create namespace**

```
$ kubectl create ns test
```

**Creating Quota**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: test
spec:
  hard:
    requests.memory: "100Mi"  
    limits.memory: "200Mi"

resourcequota/test created

$ kubectl describe quota -n test
Name:            test
Namespace:       test
Resource         Used  Hard
--------         ----  ----
limits.memory    0     200Mi
requests.memory  0     100Mi
```

In above example I don't have any pods whih are using memory.

**Scenario**

2 pods with `50Mi requests` and `100Mi` Limit each.

***pod.yaml***

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-1
  namespace: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "50Mi"
      limits:
        memory: "100Mi"
```

After that, `Used` value of `Quota` has been chagnged.

```
$ kubectl describe quota -n test
Name:            test
Namespace:       test
Resource         Used   Hard
--------         ----   ----
limits.memory    100Mi  200Mi
requests.memory  50Mi   100Mi
```

If I would create second pod with the same values but with name `nginx-2`, Kubernetes allows me to do it as `Hard` values won't be exceeded. `Used` and `Hard` values will be the same

```
$ kubectl describe quota -n test
Name:            test
Namespace:       test
Resource         Used   Hard
--------         ----   ----
limits.memory    200Mi  200Mi
requests.memory  100Mi  100Mi
```

However, I won't be able to create `nginx-3` as it would exceeded `Hard` value. You will receive error:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "pod.yaml": pods "nginx-3" is forbidden: exceeded quota: test, requested: limits.memory=100Mi,requests.memory=50Mi, used: limits.memory=200Mi,requests.memory=100Mi, limited: limits.memory=200Mi,requests.memory=100Mi
```

In above example `resourcequota/test` set limitations on `test` namespace.

- `limits.memory` is referring to pod's `spec.containers.resources.limits.memory`.
- `requests.memory` is referring to pod's `spec.containers.resources.requests.memory`.

Created `quota` won't allow to create pods if `limits` and `requests` will exceed `Hard` value in the `quota`.

In `$ kubectl describe quota test -n test`, `Usage` value is sum of all pod's limits in this `namespace` (currently in use). `Hard` is maximum value which cannot be exceeded.

### Conclusion

`Used` value of `Quota` is number of resources which are already using in this `namespace`. It can be number of `pods` or amount of `memory` or `cpu`.
`Hard` value of `Quota` is maximum number of `pods` or maximum threshold for `memory` to use. If it will exceed `Hard` value, particular resource won't be created.

### Useful links

- [How to use Kubernetes resource quotas](https://opensource.com/article/20/12/kubernetes-resource-quotas)
- [Limit Ranges](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/limit-range/)

Please let me know if you still have some questions.

Comment: not fully, what is the difference between limits.memory for Used & Hard, requests.memory for Used & Hard?

Comment: Limits.memory for Used it is limit for POD. Limits.memory for Hard it is limit for namespace. Request.memory for Used it is limit for POD. Request.memory for Hard it is limit for Namespace. Right?

Comment: @Epic555 I've used limits and requests to make it more clear. Please I've updated my answer, please check it and let me know if you still have questions.