# Unable to provide config files to puma in kubernetes using command/args section of kubernets Deployment yam file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, kubernetes, sinatra

What could be the reason of Deployment not being able to see config files?

This is a part from Deployment

```
command: ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb"]

already tried with ./config/.. and using args instead of command
```

I'm getting `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - config/puma.rb`

Everything used to work fine with docker-compose

**When I keep the last line (CMD) from the Dockerfile below and omit the `command:` in Deployment, everything works fine** but, to reuse the image for sidekiq, I need to provide config files.

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.7.2

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential ca-certificates libpq-dev nodejs postgresql-client yarn vim -y

ENV APP_ROOT /var/www/app

RUN mkdir -p $APP_ROOT

WORKDIR $APP_ROOT

COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
COPY public public/
RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install

# tried this
COPY config config/ 

COPY . .

EXPOSE 9292

# used to have this line but I want to reuse the image
# CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb"]
```

**error message**

```
bundler: failed to load command: puma (/usr/local/bundle/bin/puma)
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - config/puma.rb
```

**upd**

It seems that the issue was related to wrong paths and misunderstanding of command and args fields. The following config worked for me. It also possible there were cache issues with docker(happened to me earlier)

```
          command:
            - bundle
            - exec
            - puma
          args:
            - "-C"
            - "config/puma.rb"
```

Comment: try `COPY config $APP_ROOT/config/`

Comment: I think using `WORKDIR` and `COPY . .` copies this folder already

Comment: I think `COPY . .` will copy to the `.` location and not to the `WORDIR`, see the [example](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement) in docs. this could  be verified if you could try with `COPY config $APP_ROOT/config/` and if it works.

Comment: This image works fine when I don't use `command` inside of Deployment and when I keep the CMD at the bottom of dockerfile. It also works fine with docker-compose(but I used `context: build` there) This is not the problem of copying in the dockerfile

Comment: Did you try to use `commands` and `args` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66434023/) ? In what folder you are when you are entering the container and where is that file located in your image?

Comment: Do you have any `volumeMounts:` or anything else in your Deployment spec that would change the container filesystem?  It shouldn't make a difference, but does changing `command:` to `args:` help at all?  (Kubernetes `command:` matches Docker `ENTRYPOINT`, and `args:` matches `CMD`, confusingly; but what you show doesn't have an `ENTRYPOINT`.)

Comment: @kirqe could you elaborate your solution and post it as an answer? It might help other community members.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason providing commands inside of `values.yaml` doesn't seem to work properly.

But it works when commands are provided through template.

There's the following section in the `app/templates/deployment.yaml` of my app. Everything works fine now.

```
      containers:     
        - name: {{ .Values.app.name }}
          image: {{ .Values.app.container.image }}        
          command: 
            - bundle
            - exec
            - puma
          args:
            - "-C"
            - "config/puma.rb"
```

I have also found this k8s rails demo https://github.com/lewagon/rails-k8s-demo/blob/master/helm/templates/deployments/sidekiq.yaml

As you can see the commans section is provided through `templates/../name.yaml` rather than `values.yaml`